# UIWebView Size Incorrect When Rotating

Tags: ios, webview, frame

I have a UIWebView that only cover majority of the right part of the screen.
To do this, I specify the frame size and position for portrait orientation using the frame property.
`webView.frame=CGRectMake(220,100,548,875);`

When the device is rotated to landscape, I specify a new frame for landscape orientation:
`webView.frame=CGRectMake(300,73,724,638);`

The problem is when I rotate the webView from portrait to landscape and to portrait again and i changed the frame to the original one, its width is only a half from before..

Here are my codes and function called to resize the frames:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
    }
    else if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        [self showLandscape];
    }
    else if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        [self showPortrait];
    }
}

-(void)showLandscape
{
.
.
.
webView.frame=CGRectMake(300,73,724,638);
.
.
.
}

-(void)showPortrait
{
.
.
.
webView.frame=CGRectMake(220,100,548,875);
.
.
.
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: is `webView` created dynamically?

Comment: Yes the webView is created dynamically

Comment: can you take some screenshots, please?

Comment: okay... it seems there is problem with these images' links. :)

Comment: here are 3 screenshots:
http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/7218/iossimulatorscreenshotjk.png
http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/7633/iossimulatorscreenshotj.png
http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/7633/iossimulatorscreenshotj.png

Comment: what is the yellow stuff behind the `webView`? is it an `UIView`? if yes, what is the size of it?

Comment: it is a background color of self.view i made just to check its subviews position. full screen size of course.

Comment: okay then... I'm thinking. how do you init the `viewView` object?

Comment: What do you mean viewView? is it webView?
these are my codes


webView=[[UIWebView alloc] init];
  webView.delegate=self;
  webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
  
webView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
  webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
  webView.autoresizesSubviews=YES;

  
  webView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
 
[webView loadRequest:request];

sorry a little bit messy. I'm new with stack overflow and iOS also..

Comment: where do you set the new `frame` value for the `webView`? could you update your question with this code fragment? _(I've tested the same process with a dynamic `UIWebView` instance, my version is working fine.)_ so, could you provide the code fragments where you set the `frame` property of you instance, please?

Comment: it's edited.. just check the question above.. thanks

Comment: If you are setting its frame manually on rotation, why do you need an autoresizingMask?

Comment: **UPDATE:** I've tested a same `UIWebView` instance what you've inited, it is working fine for me. I'm wanting for your code fragments then.

Comment: I deleted the autoresizingMask and it works perfectly.. thanks..

Comment: @hwaxxer I've tried to remove or add this property as well, but in both of cases the rotation is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I've done, **it is working well**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIWebView *_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    // when I add these line it is also working well (!!!) on my device
    //_webView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    //_webView.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
    //_webView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; 
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
    [_webView setFrame:CGRectMake(220.f, 100.f, 548.f, 875.f)];
}
```

and I've added the following code as well:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    for (UIView *_temporaryView in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([_temporaryView isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
            if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)){
                [_temporaryView setFrame:CGRectMake(220.f, 100.f, 548.f, 875.f)];
            } else {
                [_temporaryView setFrame:CGRectMake(300.f, 73.f, 724.f, 638.f)];
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

*please, compare it with your code and find the differences, if you don't want to provide you code fragment to find the anomaly.*

Comment: I deleted the line
webView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
and it works already. Thanks for your reply. :)